# Read every file stored on device or SD card?

Tags: external-sd, storage, files

Flash storage devices (NAND cells) are nutorious for slowly losing charge over time.

Many USB sticks have automatic data retention when idle, but I doubt that MicroSD has automatic data retention.

How do I read every single file saved on the mSD card?

Comment: Recursive listing (ls -R) or 'find' will read metadata of every file less or more, though not complete files.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is installing an Android terminal emulator such as *Termux* or *jackpal.androidterm* (which I have).

```
cd /storage/extSdCard/
cp -R -v . /dev/null
```

*-v* adds verbosity and shows which file is being read momentarily. 
[*“extSdCard”* might be ####-#### (hexadecimal characters such as 0612-2FA5).](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103478/how-to-get-path-to-external-sd-card)

*/dev/null* is a *black hole* in Unix/Linux based operating systems. Everything put in there is gone. But what the command does is **copying** all the files into *nothing*, hence the source files stay the same, just getting read.

---

#### Alternatives:

```
grep -R "Any Text" #if working directory is already selected using the “cd” command.
```

Or `grep -R "Any Text" /storage/`*[path to MicroSD card]*

This will quickly search every file recrusively for text, causing all data to get read.

You can also redirect the output of the command to *>>/dev/null* or *>>/dev/zero*.

---

Another alternative is using a hashsum generating command (`md5sum` needs the lowest processing ressources for the same amount of data), but that's less efficient because it needs to generate a hashsum. This process requires additional system ressources.

Answer (score 2):

Open
   /sdcard/
/sdcard/ will link you to the correct directory of the sdCard, this is for compatibility i believe.

To really make sure you have every sectors data,

- Switch Off your Device.
- Remove the SD Card from your device.
- Place the SD Card in an adapter ( microSD to SupportedSlot )
- Place the adapter into your computer.
- Clone the Disk to a  .img  file

---

- Don't choose compression with cloning, or else unused sectors ( marked as replaceable ) will be ignored and not cloned into the image file or partition.        **bad for data recovery purposes**

Comment: One can also run `badblocks -vv /dev/mmcblk0`. But that's with the PC. How to do it with Android directly?